# get_queryset() in MonthArchiveView returns all objects instead objects created only in requested month

Tags: python, django

Why `get_queryset()` from MonthArchiveView returns all objects from my model instead objects `created` only in requested month?

```
class BudgetMonthlyView(MonthArchiveView):
    template_name = 'budget/monthly.html'
    model = FinanceData
    date_field = "created"
    make_object_list = False
    allow_future = False
    month_format = '%m'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BudgetMonthlyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print(self.get_queryset()) #return all objects from FinanceData model
        print(context['object_list']) #works fine
        return context
```

Comment: Please add the FinanceData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the way that the `MonthArchiveView` is implemented. If you look at [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9269dec05efae5deb89912a5b9a98ae75acdfff9/django/views/generic/dates.py#L290), you can see that the `object_list` is returned by the `get_dated_items` method.

It's probably implemented this way because the date archive views add other things to the context as well as the `object_list`, for example `date_list`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class BudgetMonthlyView(MonthArchiveView):
    template_name = 'budget/monthly.html'
    queryset = FinanceData.objects.all()
    date_field = "created"
    make_object_list = True
    allow_future = False
    month_format = '%m'
    paginate_by = 50
    context_object_name = 'object_list'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BudgetMonthlyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        month = self.get_month() # get month
        context['month'] = self.queryset.filter(created__month=month) # you can aggregate for this month ' .aggregate(Sum('cost'))['cost__sum'] '
        print(context['object_list']) #works fine
        return context
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.